# How to extract numbers with separation in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, excel-2019

Does anyone knows any formula to extract the number with separation (dot, comma) from cell `A1` to cell `B1`?

Example, I want to extract `2,590.00` from cell `A1` which has the following value:

```
[sum: 2,590.00]
```

I got the formula below that works nice, however is just getting all numbers e.g. `259000`

```
{=TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,IFERROR((MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1)*1),""))}
```

I appreciate every support

Comment: Have you considering changing the number format of the cells with the results?

Comment: the number is coming from external font, I would like to change but if I use the formula is going be awesome, quick and easy way for me to build the report.

Comment: What is the role of `Q3` in our formula, my understanding is that only cell `A1` will be required.

Comment: Would it always have this format? Or is the content more dynamic? Meaning; does the number always start at position 7?

Comment: you are right @DavidLeal it was my fault let me change

Comment: @DavidNunes can you try this and let me know `=MAX(IFERROR(--MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"]",""),ROW($ZZ1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,LEN(A1))),LEN(A1)),0))`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya this formula below it works perfect and helps me! =MAX(IFERROR(--MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"]",""),ROW($ZZ1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,LEN(A1))),LEN(A1)),0))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under O365 you can try the following in cell `B1` which is a very concise approach:

```
=TEXTAFTER(TEXTBEFORE(A1,"]"), "sum: ")
```

Here is the output:

[image: sample excel file]

For [excel-2019](/questions/tagged/excel-2019), similar idea but using `SUBSTITUTE` instead to remove the prefix (`[sum:` ) and the suffix (`]`):

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"[sum: ",""),"]","")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a formula like as below:

[image]

• Formula used in cell `B1`

```
=MAX(IFERROR(--MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"]",""),ROW($ZZ1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,LEN(A1))),LEN(A1)),0))
```

• With OFFICE 365, you can try this in cell `C1`

```
=--INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(A1,{":","[","]"},,1),,2)
```

• Formula used in cell `D1`

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TEXTAFTER(A1," "),"]","")*1
```

Comment: @DavidLeal post edit doesn't shows that, it was from the beginning, never mind, I don't post solutions without OP query history. Furthermore, OP has never accepted anyone's solution yet, which surprises more isnt it weird.

Comment: Mayukh. No all changes are reflected in the history there is a grace period. I don’t know the duration of this grace period. During this period changes are not reflected in the history. I hope @DavidNunes will solve the mistery, :-). Anyway good talking to you.